# Python - How to Output Ping results to Pandas DataFrame Object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, parsing, ping

This might seem trivial, but I've been running into a roadblock researching how to store the results of `ping somedomain.com` to a Pandas Dataframe object.

I've tried using modules like **pingparsing** and **pythonping** but am not getting anywhere.

### Objective:

Hardcode a ping target (ie: `ping_target = 'google.com'`)
Send results of pinging target to a dataframe object
Use pandas to extract data (ie: `pd.describe(ping_results)` )

### What I tried

```py
import pingparsing
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from textwrap import dedent

parser = pingparsing.PingParsing()

ping_parser = pingparsing.PingParsing()
transmitter = pingparsing.PingTransmitter()
transmitter.destination = "google.com"
transmitter.count = 10
result = transmitter.ping()
stats = parser.parse(dedent(result))

# This "should" return each icmp_reply from the stats object.                     
for icmp_reply in stats.icmp_replies:
    print(icmp_reply)
```

### Error

````
<ipython-input-36-b7c7a41d50df> in <module>
     14 transmitter.count = 10
     15 result = transmitter.ping()
---> 16 stats = parser.parse(dedent(result))
     17 
     18 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\textwrap.py in dedent(text)
    428     # all lines.
    429     margin = None
--> 430     text = _whitespace_only_re.sub('', text)
    431     indents = _leading_whitespace_re.findall(text)
    432     for indent in indents:

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object```
## Note
I'm not stuck on using this pingparsing module and would prefer a more organic way using python stdout but want to see if this can be possible without parsing heavily using regex. Ideally I'd want to use as much vanilla python or builtins before converting output to dataframe.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution to the problem:

```py
# Import packages
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define ping target, ping the target, and then store results as string
ping_target = 'google.com'
results = os.popen('ping ' + ping_target).read()
print(results)

# Extract the times from the results string
times = []
for i in range(4):
    timeIdx = results.index('time')
    time = results[timeIdx+5:timeIdx+7]
    
    results = results[timeIdx+10:]
    
    times.append(time)
    
# Put data into pandas DataFrame
d = {'PingNum': np.arange(1,5), 'PingTime_ms': times}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The initial "results" variable looks like this

[image: Ping results]

There's no need for those fancy libraries, the os library will do the job! 
**NOTE: This solution is good for Windows, since the number of ping times returned is always 4.**

Comment: Thank you for this! This is great. I can see where I messed up with my original attempts now.